# MySQL query failing

Tags: mysql, database, join

This MySQL query is failing and i just can not figure out why. Any help is appreciated and if you need more information, please let me know.

---

NEW QUERY and NEW ERROR

```
select * 
from 
(select 
classId as `Class ID`, mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2.studentId as `Student ID`, quizId as `Quiz ID`, quizGrade as `Quiz Grade`, mjla_db.StudentTable2.lastName, mjla_db.StudentTable2.firstName 
from mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2, mjla_db.StudentTable2 
where (mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2.studentId=mjla_db.StudentTable2.studentId)) 
as A 
where classId 
in (select mjla_db.ClassTable2.classId 
from mjla_db.ClassTable2 
where mjla_db.ClassTable2.teacherId='T1');

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'classId' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'
```

---

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
        classId as 'Class ID',
        studentId as 'Student ID',
        quizId as 'Quiz ID',
        quizGrade as 'Quiz Grade',
        mjla_db.StudentTable2.lastName,
        mjla_db.StudentTable2.firstName
    from
        mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2,
        mjla_db.StudentTable2
    where
        (mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2.studentId = mjla_db.StudentTable2.studentId)
    ) as A
where
    A.classId in 
        (select
            mjla_db.ClassTable2.classId
        from
            mjla_db.ClassTable2
        where
            mjla_db.ClassTable2.teacherId='T1'
        );
```

---

```
describe StudentRecordTable2;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| classId   | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| studentId | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| quizGrade | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| quizId    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
describe ClassTable2;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| classId       | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| className     | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| classSection  | varchar(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| classSemester | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| classYear     | varchar(4)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| teacherId     | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
describe StudentTable2;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| studentId       | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lastName        | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| firstName       | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| studentPassword | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the bactick / backquote (`) character to quote your column names, not the single quote character (').

Also, you are aliasing classId to `Class ID` in the first subquery, but then referencing A.classId in the outer `where` clause.

Comment: Changed to backticks, (this was not causing a problem earlier). I am posting the new error in the OP.

Comment: How do i fix that problem with A.classId?

Comment: And while doing that, you destroyed the nice formatting that actually made your code readable.

Comment: You aliased it to \`Class ID\` so you would use A.\`Class ID\`

Comment: Bactick operator is indeed the caracter used to quote column name. In particular backquoting  table and field names allows for having spaces in those names.

Comment: Fixed it with the A.`Class ID`. Thanks robot for all the help!

Comment: Your next homework assignment is to get rid of the subqueries!

Comment: Can you help me with that? Like, what would be a good example of that? I want to do this the right way.

Comment: Start with the wikipedia article on [SQL Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are selecting from both `StudentRecordTable2` and `StudentTable2` you can't just do a `SELECT studentId` because that column name is used in both tables and mysql doesn't know which one you want. You need to specify which table's `studentId` you want, by prefixing it with the table name like you have done later in your query. `mjla_db.StudentTable2.studentId` for example.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from (select ...)` is incorrect syntax. `select * from` must be followed by table name(s). I think you just need to get rid of the first one, and just use the query that is inside the brackets.

And I am not sure you can use spaces inside the identifier used with the `AS`.

Comment: It was working before i added the "AS" statements. So i am sure that syntax is fine. However, i could still be wrong... will look into further.

Comment: Then maybe the spaces inside the identifiers used with the "AS" are not allowed.

Comment: The spaces in the identifiers have been working up to this point.

Comment: @KayKay is incorrect, [subqueries are allowed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) in MySQL. They should be avoided where possible, but are legal.

Comment: What would you suggest instead ObscureRobot?

Comment: It looks like the two subqueries could be combined together with a join on classId.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. I had checked on he W3Cschools site and it said only table names. It might be specific to MySQL then?

Comment: Don't use W3Schools, use the MySQL documentation. W3Schools documentation is incomplete and out of date.